# How can I use full outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, full-outer-join

I need use join 2 table show all data.

**Exam**

**Table Contact**

```
numCode | fullName
00001   | Midna 
00002   | Klog
00003   | Porla
00004   | Seka
00005   | Mila
```

**Table dateFile**

```
numCode | dateCurr
00001   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
00002   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
00005   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
```

**Code Sql Server**

```
SELECT df.numCode as 'numCode', tf.dateCurr as 'dateCurr'
FROM dateFile df Full Outer join Contact ct On ct.numCode = df.numCode
WHERE df.dateCurr = '2012-10-29'
```

**Output**

```
numCode | dateCurr
00001   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
00002   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
00005   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
```

**But I need output get:**

```
numCode | dateCurr
00001   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
00002   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
00003   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000  (Insert Date from choose datetime)
00004   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000  (Insert Date from choose datetime)
00005   | 2012-10-29 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT df.numCode as 'numCode', 
       coalesce(tf.dateCurr, '2012-10-29') as 'dateCurr'
FROM dateFile df Full Outer join Contact ct 
On ct.numCode = df.numCode and df.dateCurr = '2012-10-29'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select c.numCode,ISNULL(d.dateCurr,'2012-10-29 00:00:00.000') from Contact c left join dateFile d
on c.numCode = d.numCode
```